# How to get file location in C# from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In My project ,i have a folder with Details.aspx page. and i have Details.xml file outside of the folder.
Now i want to get file location of  Details.xml to  Details.aspx.cs page.
i have tried different ways, but i am not getting file location.

Details.aspx.cs :

```
 private void GenerateXMLFile()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsJobsDetails = new DataSet();
            dsJobsDetails = GetJobDetails();               
            string fileLoc = Server.MapPath("Details.xml"); 

            if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                try
                {
                    dsJobsDetails.WriteXml(fileLoc);
                    Response.Redirect("Details.xml");
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Please tell me how to get file location.
Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string fileLoc = Server.MapPath("~/Details.xml");
```

Will give you the full path to the `Details.xml` file on your server, something like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\Details.xml`.

You can return that as URL by redirecting to it for example, using `~/` (the application root, in URL form):

```
Response.Redirect("~/Details.xml");
```

This will translate into a redirect to something like `http://server/Application/Details.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

For example your file structure is like this

```
/Details.aspx.cs
/MyFolder/Details.xml
```

Then you can get the file location by this

```
string fileLoc = Server.MapPath("/MyFolder/Details.xml");
```

Comment: My .xml file is located outside of the folder i,e /Details.xml and .cs file in folder ie. /MyFolder/Details.aspx.cs..